# iOS 11 UIImagePickerController not displaying privacy alert - how to force display permission dialog?

Tags: objective-c, swift3, ios11, xcode9, info.plist

I have an app that has been rejected from the store for not displaying the privacy dialog when selecting a photo with `UIImagePickerController`. 
I tried a different project and pasted my code below, still am not getting any privacy alerts.

The user taps the button to select a photo, a list of camera rolls is displayed, a picture can be picked. Everything works, except the alert before this operation asking the user to allow the operation is not displayed.

On app submission there has been no errors or warnings, only the app review team refused to let the app through for not showing the alert.

**How can I force the app to display privacy alert before accessing photo library?**

```
- (IBAction)pickAction:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To pick photos for analysis</string>
```

I tried a brand new project with Swift3 and also am not getting any privacy/permission alert dialog with code below:

```
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBAction func btnClicked() {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum){
            print("Button capture")

            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

        })

//        imageView.image = image
    }
```

Comment: Re: the review, is your app for iOS11-only?

Comment: Take a look at `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` and `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`. There is a lot of iOS 10 and iOS 11 specific behavior. (I'm on iOS 11, we don't ask for perms, and it works for us. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 11 introduced new "Photos" framework with photo library object which can explicitly request permissions from the user:

You have to use like this :

```
import Photos
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                print("authorized")
            case .denied:
                print("denied")
            default:
                print("default")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean PhotoKit (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit), that's been out since iOS 8.